# nginx was forced to use /usr/share/nginx/html

Tags: nginx, nginx-config

I installed Nginx using `yum install nginx` and then deleted the conf.d and default.conf folders along with their contents.

After modifying the nginx.conf file only and reload Nginx, the reverse proxy and load balancing are working fine.

However, when accessing port 80, Nginx always forces to read the index.html file from /usr/share/nginx/html. And the same nginx.conf works fine in other machine.

What could be the issue?

Here is the config of port 80:

```
worker_processes 1;
pid /usr/local/nginx/logs/nginx.pid;
events {
    worker_connections  1024;
    #accept_mutex on;
  }
error_log /usr/local/nginx/logs/error.log;
http {
  include mime.types;
  default_type application/octet-stream;
  keepalive_timeout 650;
  client_max_body_size 100m;
  client_header_buffer_size 32k;
  client_body_buffer_size 8m;
  sendfile on;
  tcp_nopush on;
  tcp_nodelay on;
  types_hash_max_size 2048;
  proxy_read_timeout 600;
  server_tokens off;
  log_format main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

  #===================================================================================
  # other reverse proxy and load balancing configs which works fine are not showing...
  #===================================================================================

  server {
    server_name localhost;
    listen 80;
    location / {
      root html; # trying to access html folder
      index index.html index.htm; # to use index.html in html folder
    }
    location = /50x.html {
      root html;
    }
  }
}
```

[image]

I always receive a 403 Forbidden error page when visit port 80. However, when I place the index.html file in /usr/share/nginx/html, everything works fine. This indicates that my configuration for port 80 is not taking effect or is being overridden by something else.

Answer (score 0):

The problem of getting a 403 forbidden error may be due to `autoindex` not having been enabled.